# How to hide a new message notification when user is actively chatting with the sender in flutter

Tags: flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am implementing a chat feature in my flutter app. I use FCM to send a notification when a new message comes. I propagate the FCM message to flutter local notification when the notification came while the app is in the foreground. My problem is I don't want to show the local notification when the user is actively chatting with the sender.

I have firebase messaging configuration in app.dart and I have another stateful widget to show the message details and chat. I will get `fromUid` from notification data. I have also open chat message UID's in the message details widget. I am trying to compare these two UIDs values from notification and message detail widget and if the UIds are the same don't notify.

I try using change notifier and RouteObserver but it's not working fine. I will love any help and recommendations.

Comment: did you get the answer? @Sinshaw Demisse

Answer (score 1):

I have implemented a similar feature in my app. This is what I did.
I am using flutter and hive for local storage.

Do this when entering chat view

`Hive.box("settings").put("currentChatId", xxx)`

And on popping the page, set it to null again

On receiving notifications, before showing local notification you can just use `.get("currentChatId")!= null && id==notificationId` to check if it should show it or not.